# Why won't this object method return a boolean value Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dom, methods, this

My app's js file includes this bit here:

```
var drawer = document.getElementById('b_001');

drawer.isOpen = function() {
  this.classList.contains('open');
};
```

When I call it in the console, `drawer.isOpen()`, I expect a boolean value, `true` or `false`. However, `undefined` is returned instead. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to *return* it:

```
drawer.isOpen = function() {
  return this.classList.contains('open');
//^ here  
};
```

If a function doesn't return anything, the return value is considered `undefined`, as this snippet demonstrates:

```js
var report = document.querySelector('#result');

report.innerHTML += doStuff(5);        // nothing returned
report.innerHTML += '<br>'+addFive(5); // a result is returned

function doStuff(val) {
  val = val || 0;
  val += 5;
}

function addFive(val) {
  val = val || 0;
  val += 5;
  return val;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This was answered 1st but it has only one upvote but the answer got 3 upvotes,why?

Answer (score 3):

you need a return statement

```
 return this.classList.contains('open');
```